# Клиент-сервер ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, асинхронность, запрос

Всем доброго времени суток.
Проблема такая: 
Необходимо асинхронно обновлять данные на экране пользователя без его участия.
Т.е. своего рода как в VK нам приходят уведомления о событиях.

Можно делать циклический запрос с задержкой на сервер и если данные изменились от предыдущих то и на клиенской части изменить.

Кто знает, как правильно осуществить передачу клиенту с сервера без запроса клиента.
Зараннее спасибо.

Comment: > как правильно осуществить передачу клиенту с сервера без запроса клиента

Гуглите

> commet, long polling, websocket's, socket.io, pusher, .....

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая штука как каналы... они как раз для подобного типа работы с данными... напимер 
[Google channels](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview)
или 
[Pusher](http://pusher.com/)

Comment: Если не сложно, можете пояснить принципе их работы? Т.е. это реально лучше, чем делать setInterval или это просто удобнее типа?

Comment: там немного принци другой, сет интервал постоянно запросы генерирует, а каналы это что то типа постоянно поддерживаемоего соединения, и как только что то происходит по каналу уходит событие, которое обрабатывается клиентом

Comment: Тогда если вы знаете, можете посоветовать, где глянуть про то, как это сделать самому? Отдельный вопрос мне создавать не хочется, потому что сейчас мне нет острой необходимости в таком функционале, но понять принцип работы хочу, самому может сделать в ознакомительных целях.

Answer (score 1):

Один из возможных вариантов - вызывать функцию обновления данных через определенный промежуток времени с помощью метода *setInterval (function, delay)*. Например,

```
setInterval(myFunction, 1000)
```

Comment: Я об этом писал: "Можно делать циклический запрос с задержкой на сервер и если данные изменились от предыдущих то и на клиенской части изменить."

Comment: > Я об этом писал ...

Тогда в чем вопрос?